# Register a sitecore goal only once

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

Is it possible to register a sitecore goal and assign Engagement Value Points (EVP) only once.  i.e. the first time a user hit's a page with a goal assigned (and not register it on subsequent visits)? If so, how is this done configured - or would we need an engagement plan to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track; this is what Engagement Plans are for; tracking interactions with a visitor over a series of visits and/or a period of time.

What you're wanting to do could be accomplished with a tiny bit of custom code. In the past, I've sometimes has a "Goal Trigger" rendering that could be added to a page, with code to trigger a named goal. That rendering could then be subject to personalisation conditions and optionally triggered - for instance based on previous visits.

Bit of info on custom triggering http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2014/10/28/whats-new-about-goals-in-sitecore-8/, if it helps you.